# Rails Paperclip and aws s3 integration error "uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::Aws"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have gone through different posts but got no help, I am trying to upload my images to Amazon **S3** I double checked my asw credentials they all are correct, here are the required files please help

> Gemfile

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'devise'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0.beta1"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'bootstrap-material-design'
gem 'nested_scaffold'
```

> config/environments/development.rb

```
  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: "bucketName",
    access_key_id: "xoxoxo",
    secret_access_key: "secret_key"

  }
}
```

> config/initializers/paperclip.rb

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

And while uploading Iam still getting the error

> NameError in CorporateTrainersController#create
>   **uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::Aws**

```
Extracted source (around line #29):          
  # POST /corporate_trainers.json
  def create
    @corporate_trainer = CorporateTrainer.new(corporate_trainer_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @corporate_trainer.save
```

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: @Pavan Yes, of course **bundle install** and **bundle update**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just drop your gemfile version. may be it help  you.

```
    gem "paperclip",'4.3.6' #last stable version

    gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'


than bundle install
```

Comment: thanks your answer it  gave me the idea, issue was with paperclip 5.0 beta version, I took the last stable version of paperclip and `gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'` and everything was working fine